# Java: ImageIcon - image file updating but image icon in Java frame not

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, imageicon

I have got a `ImageIcon` in a `Jlabel` in a `JFrame` (Java GUI).

The `ImageIcon` should get updated based on pressing a *Calculate* button (i.e. `calcButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()` ) with part of the code in the method:

```
icon2 = new ImageIcon("M:\\Repos\\rtrans\\radTransPlot.png");
Plot1.setIcon(icon2);
frame.add(Plot1,gc);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

The initial `ImageIcon` *(icon1)* is blank:

```
public class RadTransGui 
{
private ImageIcon icon1 = new ImageIcon("M:\\Repos\\rtrans\\radTransPlotEmpty.png");
private ImageIcon icon2;
private JLabel Plot1 = new JLabel(icon1);
```

and gets properly updated based on the first *Calculate* button press but not after subsequent presses of *Calculate* button. The contents of *M:\Repos\rtrans\radTransPlot.png* gets updated correctly each time *Calculate* is pressed.

I have tried setting the ImageIcon to null and adding and removing the JLabel to the frame each time the *Calculate* button is pressed.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: you should share more code, including the code inside actionPerformed

Comment: I printed the contents `System.out.println(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("M:\\Repos\\rtrans\\radTransPlot.png"));` after first *Calculate* press: `sun.awt.image.ToolkitImage@258903c8` and after another *Calculate* press: `sun.awt.image.ToolkitImage@258903c8`

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the DB. 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556). E.G. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/418556) hot links to an image embedded in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10861852/418556). 3) Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  ..

Comment: .. An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constructor of ImageIcon() internally uses `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage`.

You have to manually use `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage` instead of `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage`. The latter uses cache whereas the former doesn't and always returns a new instance.

```
new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("..filename.."))
```

From the javadoc of `createImage`:

> The returned Image is a new object which will not be shared with any other caller of this method or its getImage variant.

Compare with the javadoc of `getImage`:

> The underlying toolkit attempts to resolve **multiple requests** with the same filename to the **same returned Image**.
>    [...] If the image data contained in the specified file changes, the **Image object returned from this method may still contain stale information** which was loaded from the file after a prior call.

There seems to be no javadoc or spec that prescribes that ImageIcon should use cached images, so it's a perfect example of how fragile programming is if you don't know 100% what you're doing. Even if it works in one environment doesn't guarantee it always works.

Comment: Brilliant using: `icon2 = new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("M:\\Repos\\rtrans\\radTransPlot.png"));` worked! Thank you!

Comment: Is the fact that the image is stored on disk *important*? If you just wanted to update the *displayed* image you don't need to write it to file first, but I just realized I don't know if you know that.

Comment: Thanks for the thought. At the moment yes the images are stored on disk as is the intention. Of course if I was dealing with `ImageIcon` images in memory only this would be different.